# Legal obligations when designing electronics

Tags: pcb-design, production, legal

I'm planning on releasing a USB powered device, basically a AVR ATMega2560 µC with a FTDI FT232RL chip powered by USB-C.

Although I'm comfortable with the safety of the device (has fuses, ferrite beads, etc.) I'm not sure what are my legal obligations regarding consumer safety when selling the product (Europe and US at least). I'm guessing that all components need to be RoHS certified, etc.

Is there a place from which I can start reading on the requirements so that I can make sure that the devices are fully compliant?

Comment: In the US, UL is typical but not required. But you may have trouble with the market if you don't have it. Take a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10639/is-ul-approval-required-on-all-items-sold-in-the-usa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Concerning the EU market, [this](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards_en) is the main site that lists the regulation directives.

Given the product type and the typical usage of your product, you have to dig into all this regulations and check the applicable standards listed on that site.

Hint: Find a CE declaration of conformity for an existing product that is similar to your product. The declaration will contain the applicable standards. (Every product on the EU marked must have a CE DoC publicly available).

Comment: That is correct, If you are still unsure of which category your product sits, a trick is to request a quote for CE marking from a certification test lab such as TÜV SÜD in the UK, They will list all the tests that are required and the correct classification for your product. (This was suggested to me by a TÜV employee)

Comment: If the OP is in the UK, https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ce-marking is a good place to start. There are many other CE testing labs in the UK besides TÜV.